# Stateless (controlled) input

Tags: vue.js

*Stateless input* means it changes only when :value binding of parent does change. Which gives full control over what it displays, which is useful for masks and filters.

#### What I have

This solution is the one closest to what I need: https://codesandbox.io/s/mm9n7r08mx

#### The problem with existing solution

Cursor jumps to the end when I try to type something in the middle of the existing text.

#### What I need

Any working solution for stateless input or a way to fix the existing one.

#### Materials I found

- [React issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/955)
- React fiddle for credit card input `http://jsbin .com/dunutajuqo`

Comment: you can have a stateless input whose value change only on parent change (and the input can be disabled). If you want to type in the input then this still means the input is stateless? In this way you don't change the value through parent binding but through change event. So, I think you can add onChange event on input and notify the parent to change the binding value to the new one.

Comment: @Jorj The problem with onChange is that it kills reactivity. For instance, when user is typing - input will allow text to be typed. But only on Enter press or blur will result be applied. But common case is to prevent user typing things I don't want him to right from the get go.

Answer (score 1):

It's jumping because you're manually assigning a value to the field. You don't need to re-set the value during input event. The value is already in sync at that point. Posting the full code blurb here so others have context:

```
<template>
  <input
    class="com-input"
    :value="value"
    @input="setValue"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
  >
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ComInput",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setValue($event) {
      const value = $event.target.value;
      $event.target.value = this.value; // <-- DELETE THIS
      this.$emit("input", value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Removing this line makes 1st test pass but tests 2-4 fail.

Comment: @YauheniPrakopchyk you'll have to elaborate, those tests are working how I expect

Comment: I added usage example (ComMacAddressInput) to sandbox. Hope this should express the functionality I require from stateless input.